# Do I absolutely need a robots.txt file for my public-facing web sites?

Tags: search-engine

I'm reviewing a couple of my web sites to make sure my SEO bases are covered.  There are no private pages on the site in question, and we want all pages to be indexed.  Does including a robots.txt file anyway, even if it isn't needed, make my site look more reputable and important to Google?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just include a blank one regardless because without it your server is still spitting out a 404 message to the requester.  Which is probably bigger then a blank robots.txt file.

Comment: Couldn't that be considered an invalid robots.txt file?

Answer (score 3):

As per [Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40360), it's a good idea. Their instructions / guidelines are actually pretty thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Only google can answer that for you.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard), robots.txt is only for blacklisting, rate limiting, and sitemaps.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered, but the answers are all a bit old, and this question continues to come up in search results, and things have changed.

[Google now recommend](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?rd=1) the following:

> If you want search engines to index everything in your site, you don't
>   need a robots.txt file (not even an empty one).

JohnMu (of Google), also makes the [following suggestion](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/DOKE2Mhpivk/AfiOw6-zH7YJ):

> I would recommend going even a bit further, and perhaps removing the
>   robots.txt file completely.

Answer (score 0):

no, it won't.

google has its own rules to decide and won't rely on the existance of robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines will look for a robots.txt file. If it's not there, the search engine will get a 404. It's a good idea to have one even if it's blank.